Grafana colour categories based on column
I would like to create a bar chart (or pie-chart, or gauge..) where I visualize a table like this
name      count    color
"dave"       4    "red"
"charlie"   10    "blue"
"matt"      12    "green"

Now I want to use the third column ('color') as the color used for each category/bar that I am going to plot. How to do this?
I know that there are Overrides where this can be clicked manually, but I want a global color table which allows me to update this over all panels in one go.
I also see that you can set the color palette, but this doesnt allow for any table entry to be used.
Is it possible what I want?

For this you can use the "Config from query results" transform. It allows to use field values for manipulating data-related options like min, max, etc., including color.
Your query should return color names ("red", "green", ...) or hex codes ("#ff00ab") in an extra column. So your example data would work straight away.
The following example shows the simple use of the transform, which only works for single entries.

For multiple entries, you can use other settings as follows:

Field _value use as "Value Mappings / Value", select "All values"
Field _color use as "Value Mappings / Color", select "All values"

There is also an example dashboard.

Afaik, this will work only if you have a single value/series.

@ypnos As Markalex mentions, this indeed only works with one entry because you are taking 'Last*' from the colors column.

I see. Please see my edited answer for the solution in that case.

thanks, I never noticed the Value Mappings / Color options!

You're welcome. Great for me to learn as well.
